# add product in different lists for the modal window

Tags: javascript, php, magento

I have to return a product to a list that I created on my website, however when I'm on the product detail page the function works correctly, can add products to the list that I want, and where on the page are a list of products that already not happens if I have just a list to directly send it to the list but when I have more than one already not of right.

function with modal screen:

```
<script>
    var baseRegistryLink = '';
    function showRegistries(link) {
        baseRegistryLink = link;        
        <?php if ($this->getEvents(true)->count() > 1): ?>
        $('adjgiftreg_popup').show();
        <?php else: ?>
        <?php foreach ($this->getEvents() as $event): ?>
            addToGiftRegistry(<?php echo $event->getId()?>);
        <?php endforeach ?>
        <?php endif ?>
        return false;
    }
    function addToGiftRegistry(e) {
        baseRegistryLink = baseRegistryLink + 'event/' + e;
        alert('addTogiftRegistry');
        var form = $('product_addtocart_form');
        var oldFormLink = form.action;
        if (form) {
            alert('addTogiftRegistry-form');
            form.action = baseRegistryLink;
            if (!productAddToCartForm.submit()) {
                alert('addTogiftRegistry-productaddTocart');
                form.action = oldFormLink;
            }
        }
        else {
            document.location.href = baseRegistryLink;
        }
        return false;
    }
</script>
<div id="adjgiftreg_popup" style='display: none; cursor: default;' onclick="event.cancelBubble = true; if(event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation();">
    <div class='box base-mini'>
        <div class='head'>
            <h4><?php echo $this->helper('adjgiftreg')->__('Add to Registry') ?></h4>

            <div class="btn-close">
                <a href="#" onclick="event.cancelBubble = true; if(event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation(); $('adjgiftreg_popup').hide(); return false;"><img
                        src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/btn_window_close.gif') ?>"
                        alt="<?php echo $this->__('Close') ?>"/></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='content'>
            <p>
                <?php //sends to the function ?>
                <?php foreach ($this->getEvents() as $event): ?>
                    <a href="#"
                       onclick="event.cancelBubble = true; if(event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation(); return addToGiftRegistry(<?php echo $event->getId() ?>)"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($event->getFullTitle()) ?></a>
                    <br/>
                <?php endforeach ?>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

na pagina que funciona o código esta assim:

```
<a href="<?php echo $_registryUrl ?>" class="adjgiftreg_add_to" onclick="return showRegistries(this.href)"> List Present</a>
```

na pagina que não  funciona o código esta assim:

```
<a href="<?php echo $_registryUrl ?>" class="adjgiftreg_add_to" onclick="event.cancelBubble = true;
                                        if(event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation(); return showRegistries(this.href);">List Present</a>
```

the two pages (detailed product and list of product options) put the function call within the form:

```
 <form action="<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form"
                    <?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
```

**I think my mistake is involved in,then the problem is occurring in the function that this abeixo when put in the detailed product screen (in my case and view.phtml file) and when products are in grid view or list the parameter sent not arrive at the function, someone rises tell me what to do**

Code:

```
 form.action = baseRegistryLink;

            if (!productAddToCartForm.submit()) {

                alert('addTogiftRegistry-productaddTocart');

                form.action = oldFormLink;
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No more, since I could insert the following javascript code on the page of the products:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
    productAddToCartForm.submit = function (button, url) {
        if (this.validator.validate()) {
            var form = this.form;
            var oldUrl = form.action;

            if (url) {
                form.action = url;
            }
            var e = null;
            try {
                this.form.submit();
            } catch (e) {
            }
            this.form.action = oldUrl;
            if (e) {
                throw e;
            }

            if (button && button != 'undefined') {
                button.disabled = true;
            }
        }
    }.bind(productAddToCartForm);

    productAddToCartForm.submitLight = function (button, url) {
        if (this.validator) {
            var nv = Validation.methods;
            delete Validation.methods['required-entry'];
            delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required'];
            delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required-by-name'];
            // Remove custom datetime validators
            for (var methodName in Validation.methods) {
                if (methodName.match(/^validate-datetime-.*/i)) {
                    delete Validation.methods[methodName];
                }
            }

            if (this.validator.validate()) {
                if (url) {
                    this.form.action = url;
                }
                this.form.submit();
            }
            Object.extend(Validation.methods, nv);
        }
    }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
    //]]>
</script>
```